# Sound Cloud : Cannot get the user playlist

Tags: ios, soundcloud, playlist

Im trying to get the user's playlist by passing user id as follows,

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=xxxxxx
```

But the issue is it gives me error like this,

```
{"errors":[{"error_message":"401 - Unauthorized"}]}
```

Can't i access the user playlist just by passing the **Client_id**

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to access now is tracks, the api for accessing `playlist` is given below.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/405726?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

[More about SoundCloud APIs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities)

Comment: But when i used your link im getting 404 as server response. So i guess i need to first get the auth token. Now i have found a way to get the auth token. So without a auth token can we get the playlist ?

Comment: No I don't think that we can get the playlist without auth token

Comment: Was the link helpful?

Comment: HI Thanks. Found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the user ID to make an API call for their playlists:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/USER_ID/playlists.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Then you can find the playlist ID of the one you want to use. Alternatively, if you already have the playlist URL you can use resolve to get the playlist details from that:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=URL_OF_PLAYLIST&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

or use the playlist ID to make an API request for its tracks:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/PLAYLIST_ID/tracks.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

The above has been tested with my client id. If you are getting a 401 response on any of the calls then double check YOUR_CLIENT_ID.

Comment: HI Thanks. Found the solution.